# How to create a cube out of uneven sides

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, 3d, puzzle

We are given:

1. four pieces of wood; each piece is 10 cm long, 10 cm wide, and 2 cm thick
2. two pieces of wood; each piece is 12 cm long, 12 cm wide, and 2 cm thick
3. An 8 oz bottle of wood glue

Provide instructions to assemble a cube from these components. The cube must survive a drop from a height of 10 cm and remain intact.

I want to know is this even possible mathematically without cutting the wood?

Comment: It's not mathematically possible without cutting the wood.

Comment: Well, you can make a $12\times 12\times 14$ box which is $2$ cm thick everywhere. That's pretty close to a cube.

Comment: Is there a way to prove it though? That it is not mathematically possible

Comment: In the 12x12x14 cube, there will be one edge which will have a gap of 10x2x2. In that case wouldn't it be better to just stack 5 of them all up one over the other and cut of the extra bit to have a cube of 10x10x10?

Comment: @adihash No, there's no gaps in the $12\times 12\times 14$ box I am envisioning.

Comment: could you please share a diagram of it or describe the order of arrangement? I'd really love to know if that's possible!

Comment: @adihash I will if you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4336293/edit) to clarify that a 12x12x14 is acceptable. As written, you are looking for a perfect cube, so my answer is not applicable.

Comment: You could glue the 10x10x2 pieces into a 10x10x8 solid, then glue the two 12x12x2 pieces onto the top and bottom faces so as to form a solid whose *convex hull* is a cube.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a 12x12x14 box.

With the four 10x10x2 pieces glue them together thusly:

```
+--+----------+
|  |          |
|  +-------+--+
|  |       |  |
|  |       |  |
|  |       |  |
+--+-------+  |
|          |  |
+----------+--+
```

This makes a 12x12x10 frame (each side is 10+2)
Then glue the two 12x12x2 on as end caps for a 12x12x14.
I believe this is what Mike Ernest is talking about.

Every glued pair is a 10x2 surface.

If instead you have four 10x8x2, then you get a 12x12x12 cubical box with an 8x8x8 hollow center.